# Implementation of hash map

Tags: apex

```
public class Person {
    private String First_name;
    private String Last_name;

    public Person(String First_name, String Last_name) {
        this.First_name = First_name;
        this.Last_name = Last_name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (First_name + Last_name).hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person("Kanishk", "Singla");

        System.out.println(person1.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What exactly is your question and what are you trying to achieve here? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a few minor alterations. First, here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm) for what follows.

```
public class Person {
    private String First_name;
    private String Last_name;

    public Person(String First_name, String Last_name) {
        this.First_name = First_name;
        this.Last_name = Last_name;
    }

    // @Override isn't needed for this, and we need Integer
    public Integer hashCode() {
        Integer result = (First_name + Last_name).hashCode();
        return result;
    }
    // We also need an equals(Object o)
    public Boolean equals(Object o) {
        Person other = (Person)o;
        return other.First_Name?.equals(First_name) == true && other.Last_Name?.equals(Last_Name) == true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person("Kanishk", "Singla");
        // We don't have a System.out in Apex
        // System.out.println(person1.hashCode());
        System.debug(person1.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Note that I included `main` for completeness, but Apex doesn't do anything special with this method signature. You call Apex from other sources, such as from a Flow, Trigger, Visualforce Page, etc.

Comment: Your equals method appears to be wrong.

Comment: @PhilW Yep, thanks! Edited